# Make TextField Autoscroll when keyboard popsup in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my Login page code

```
Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
        child: _loading
            ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
            : SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 120.h,
                    ),
                    Image.asset(
                      "assets/splash.png",
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.2,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 60.h,
                    ),
                    TextField(
                        controller: _name,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'User Name')),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 15.h,
                    ),
                    TextField(
                        controller: _password,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password')),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 45.h,
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        check();
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        width: fullWidth(context),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: AppColor.mainThemeColor,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            "Login",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
      )),
    );
```

The issue with this page is that whenever I click on any text field it hides under the keyboard even after wrapping it under SingleChildScrollView it does not allow me to scroll. I even tried **resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false** but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Padding(
padding: EdgeInsets.only(
bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
child: TextField(
autofocus: true,
),
),
);

Comment: pedding  MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom try  this  code

Answer (score 0):

You can use GlobalKey to solve your problem
like this

```
class test extends StatelessWidget {
  final textFieldKey = GlobalKey<State<StatefulWidget>>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          //...
          TextField(
            key: textFieldKey,
              onTap: () {
                autoScroll(textFieldKey: textFieldKey);
            }
          )
          //...
        ]
      )
    );
  }
  Future<void> autoScroll({required GlobalKey textFieldKey}) async {
    final keyContext = textFieldKey.currentContext;
    if (keyContext != null) {
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500)).then(
          (value) =>
          Scrollable.ensureVisible(
            keyContext,
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
            curve: Curves.linear
          )
      );
    }
  }
}
```

It worked for me